# How do I get bash with readline support from Nix?

Tags: terminal, bash, package-management, open-source

I am experimenting with the [Nix package manager](http://nixos.org/nix/) on macOS. The `bash` package I got from Nix doesn’t seem to have readline support enabled:

```
$ nix-env -i bash
installing ‘bash-4.3-p46’
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/468xvd20nj86yr6k16g2918849f3w7pn-user-environment’
created 119 symlinks in user environment
$ bash
Restored session: Thu Nov 24 14:21:31 CET 2016
$ foo^A^K
```

How do I get Bash with readline from Nix?

Comment: Have you tried `nix-env -i readline`?

Comment: Didn’t previously. Did just now, didn’t help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you passing a boolean true to the expression for the 'interactive' attribute? It appears this is required in the [expression for the bash package](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/f37566d3962d2ef1f2a518d8e5d794e0bea6d8ff/pkgs/shells/bash/4.4.nix#L1) for readline support.

There's also [an expression with the boolean already supplied](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/f67061c1de847f310d1569cfabf98fef8fb09d4e/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix#L4475) so `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.bashInteractive` should give bash with readline support enabled.

Comment: I didn’t know the right syntax to install packages by attributes, this looks like it should work. I have already aborted my Nix experiment (too much hassle right now), but when I return to it later, I will give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: @zoul: Installing by attribute is definitely the recommended way. There is talk of making it the default way as well, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `bash-interactive`, instead of `bash`, like so:

```
nix-env -i bash-interactive
```